# Is there a scraping solution to output a div content to a text file and check for repeats?

Tags: web-scraping, automation

I'm trying to set up a quality assurance automation to check for repeats over a set period in a random content component on my website. Ideally I would like to run a background script which does the following:

1. Periodically scan a selected div for changes in content
2. When a change in content is detected, output the content to a text file
   Obviously if the content has not changed since the last scrape, the output must be discarded to avoid false positives
3. When content is scraped, check previous scrapes for identical content
4. When a double up is detected, produce an email notification

I'm wondering what is out there that may be able to achieve at least part of this to have somewhere to start from.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Which URL? Which text? I want to test it myself.

Comment: Post your code attempt. What have you tried yourself, where exactly are you stuck?